# Make binary decision variable 1 when X == some value, otherwise 0 in cvxpy

Tags: python, linear-programming, cvxpy, mixed-integer-programming

I have a decision variable matrix D. I am able to obtain the max value of each column by using cp.max() and store in an another decision variable maxes. Now what I want is another decision variable that holds the indicator (0, 1) of where the max is in matrix D. In other words I want this new indicator variable to be **for each column in D**:
1 if D == max,
0 otherwise

example below, maxesi is what I want:

```
D: [[ 70.  85.  90.]
 [ 80.  85.  90.]
 [ 85.  85.  85.]
 [ 87.  95.  95.]
 [ 95. 100. 100.]
 [100.  98.  90.]
 [ 95.  90.  88.]
 [ 90.  85.  85.]
 [ 90.  80.  80.]
 [ 90.  75.  80.]]

maxes: [100. 100. 100.]

maxesi: [[ 0. 0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0. 1. 1.]
 [1.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.]]
```

I've tried the big-M methods, specifically the one posted here.https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/33/in-an-integer-program-how-i-can-force-a-binary-variable-to-equal-1-if-some-cond

but it doesn't seem to be working at least in cvxpy. the indicator never flips on and it forces other decision variables to give erroneous outcomes. what am I doing wrong? Is there a different way to formulate this into an optimization problem?

```
M = 200
delta=.0000000001
for bi, b in enumerate(bzn):
    constraints.append(M*maxesi[:,bi] >= D[:, bi] - maxes[bi] + delta)
    constraints.append(M*(1-maxesi[:, bi]) >= maxes[bi]-D[:, bi] - delta)
    constraints.append(M * maxesii[:, bi] >= maxes[bi] - D[:, bi]  + delta)
    constraints.append(M * (1 - maxesii[:, bi]) >= D[:, bi] - maxes[bi] - delta)
    constraints.append(y[:,bi] >= maxesi[:,bi] + maxesii[:,bi] - 1)
```

*y is the binary variable/indicator variable

Comment: One thing: delta seems way too small (there are feasibility tolerances to consider).

Comment: even when i try a small delta it doesn't work...like .01

Comment: I think this formulation is not doing what you want. You only have one occurrence of y: `y >= ....` I suspect this takes care of `if (...) then y=1`.There should also be something that forces y to be zero (the otherwise part).